# not getting the JSON(Object/Array) from servlet to JSP page

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, json, servlets

I am trying to fetch the value from servlet to JSP page , But I am not able to do it.
**servlet page**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String region = request.getParameter("region");
    String secretKey = request.getParameter("secret_key");
    String accessKey = request.getParameter("access_key");
    String VPC = request.getParameter("vpc");   
    LOG.info("region is  "+region);
    if(VPC == null){
        List<String> vpcs = RunEc2Command.getVPCForUSer(accessKey, secretKey, region);
        if(vpcs != null && vpcs.size() > 0) {
            LOG.info("Number of VPCs: "+vpcs.size());       
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            JSONArray jsonAraay = new JSONArray(vpcs);
            LOG.info(jsonAraay);
            out.print(jsonAraay);
            out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

and in index.jsp page , I am trying to get the JSONArray value

```
function getSubnets(){
var p = document.getElementById("vpc");

   var output2 = $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'http://localhost:8066/VMMigratorNew/ec2util',
     data: {
            "vpc":p.value
            },
    dataType:'json',
     success: function(data) {
                        $.each(data.jsaonArray, function(index){
                            var selectBox = "<select>"
                            $.each(data.jsonArray[index], function(key , value){
                                selectBox+="<option>"+key + "& value" + value + "</option>";

                            });
                            selectbox+="</select>";
                            $('vpc').html(selectBox);
                        });
            //return output2.responseText;
     }
});
```

} 
The Drop down box is not getting populated and the code for drop down box is

```
<select id="vpc" name="vpc" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose VPC" >
                                        <option value="" default selected>Select VPC</option>
                                     </select>
```

I am new to JSON, Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Did you debug it in browser? Is the server really called? Try to put few `alert(...)` or `console.log(...)` calls into your `success` handler.

Comment: the servlet is getting called and from RunEc2Command class also I am getting values to the servlet page, but just I am not able to pass the same values to the jsp page.

Comment: What do you get in success block, if logged as `console.log(data, $.isPlainObject(data))`?

Comment: I am not getting anything in the console, can you help me what I can do to solve this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
 var selectBox=""
    $.each(data.jsonArray[index], function(key , value){
                  selectBox+="<option>"+key + "& value" + value + "</option>";
                 });
    $('vpc').append(selectBox);
```

Comment: have you checked browser console?? ... please check your browser console and check is there any error notification.....

Comment: I checked and there are no errors in the browser console.